# why Image is not Display in web app made in google app script?

Tags: image, google-apps-script, svg, google-workspace

Why is not displayed in the web app made in the app script and using Google Workspace ID as well as Gmail ID, in both cases image is not displayed, but in some domain IDs, the image is displayed with the same deployed script.

I also checked the share option, which is 'anyone' and I am using the owner ID but I am still facing this issue,

I am using the code below to display my image in the web app.

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1BHV5il5YfYgoKfzCmokpvKahQDrgvZWd"
               style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; width: 100px; height: 40px;">
```

where I am using '1BHV5il5YfYgoKfzCmokpvKahQDrgvZWd' Id for displaying images in the web app as a logo.

in the console, I am getting errors like that,

Chrome Browser-

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()"

and one link with the file.

in Firefox Browser-

> "A resource is blocked by OpaqueResponseBlocking, please check browser console for details."

how we solve this issue, please anybody help me?

Comment: drive.google.com is returning a mime-type of text/plain for that data rather than whatever mime-type it's supposed to.

Answer (score -1):

Consider hosting the image on a different platform or CDN and update the image URL accordingly. Also, check whether after clearing cache of bowser

Comment: first of all thanks for suggesting to use different platform,
i use one drive but also get same error,
one this i said, other web apps that i made earlier have no issue, the are working properly in some browser and but in my profile browser in chrome it is not working.
can you guide me that code i am using in above question is correct or now any changes made in these one or two days.